# CardView limited to 9 items

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am making a app in which a activity shows some blog post data in card view. Everything Works Fine until if i have only 9 blog posts to show but when tenth post added  then card-view gets messed up like 10 post shows both in 1st cardview item and in last cardview item.
below is the code to fill the Recyclerview Cardview

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_transaction);
    LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    lm.setReverseLayout(true);
    lm.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerView =  findViewById(R.id.blog_list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lm);
    mref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("IHIAUPDATES");

}

public static class bloglistviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    static View mview;
    public bloglistviewholder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mview = itemView;
    }
    public static void setTitle(String title){
        TextView post_title = mview.findViewById(R.id.blog_title);
        post_title.setText(title);
    }
    public static void setPosteon(String postedon){
        TextView post_title = mview.findViewById(R.id.blog_postedon);
        post_title.setText(postedon);
    }
    public static void setPostby(String postedby){
        TextView post_title = mview.findViewById(R.id.blog_postedby);
        post_title.setText(postedby);
    }

    public static void setPost(String post){
        TextView post_content = mview.findViewById(R.id.blog_post);
        post_content.setText(post);
    }
    public static void setImageurl(Context ctx, String imageurl){
        ImageView post_image = mview.findViewById(R.id.blog_pic);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(imageurl).into(post_image)
        ;
    }


}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<blog_list,bloglistviewholder> rAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<blog_list, bloglistviewholder>(

            blog_list.class,
            R.layout.blog_row,
            bloglistviewholder.class,
            mref.orderByKey()
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(bloglistviewholder viewHolder, blog_list model, int position) {
            bloglistviewholder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            bloglistviewholder.setPost(model.getPost());
            bloglistviewholder.setPostby(model.getPostedby());
            bloglistviewholder.setPosteon(model.getPostedon());
            bloglistviewholder.setImageurl(getApplicationContext(),model.getImageurl());
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(rAdapter);
}
```

Xml blog_row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/blog_pic"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:padding="4dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blog_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/blog_pic"
            android:text="Apple MacBook Air Core i5 5th Gen - (8 GB/128 GB SSD/Mac OS Sierra)"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blog_postedon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/blog_title"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/blog_pic"
            android:text="13.3 Inch, 256 GB"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blog_postedby"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/blog_postedon"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/blog_pic"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="4.7"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.Inverse"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blog_post"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/blog_postedby"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/blog_pic"
            android:text="INR 56990"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

what could be wrong?
am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> what could be wrong?

You have a logic problem where you insert your data into the database, causing the same first item to show up as the 10th item. However, since you haven't shown the code, it's impossible to guess beyond that.

What have you done to debug your code?

> am i doing something wrong?

Well, you have a bug ... so ... yes? :P